# Finalizar proceso

Tags: c, winapi

Mi intención es que no se pueda ejecutar cierta aplicacion (prueba.exe) en un equipo con windows.
Ese equipo suele estar siempre encendido y con mi programa en funcionamiento, y con la pantalla bloqueada, para que puedan entrar otros usuarios.
La aplicaicón comprueba los procesos que hay en memoria y, en caso de que esté residente "prueba.exe" mata el proceso.
Esto funciona bien cuando estoy en mi sesion (siendo administrador) y abro el programa "prueba.exe" y lo mata, también funciona bien cuando abro el programa "prueba.exe" desde mi misma sesión pero lanzandola mediante runas con otro usuario (que no tiene privilegios).
El problema viene cuando otro usuario inicia sesión con su usuario sin privilegios (mi sesión de admin y mi programa sigue abierta) y ese usuario ejecuta el llamado "prueba.exe", entonces mi aplicación no mata el proceso, no entiendo el por qué.

En resumen, mi aplicación mata el proceso desde mi sesión pero si otro usuario sin ser admin inicia sesión y ejecuta el "prueba.exe" le permite ejecutarla y mi aplicación no mata el proceso.

Pongo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>

void main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        HANDLE CProc;
        PROCESSENTRY32 process;
        Sleep(1);
        CProc = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
        Process32First(CProc,&process);
        process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); //windows 10
        while(Process32Next(CProc,&process))
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,(DWORD) process.th32ProcessID);
            if(strcasecmp(process.szExeFile,"prueba.exe")==0)
            {
                printf("prueba.exe in memory");
                TerminateProcess(hProcess,0);    
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(CProc);
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado.
(Win7)

Comment: Utiliza GetLastError() justo después de llamar a la función TerminateProcess para averiguar si ha habido algún error y cuál ha sido. En función del error, ya veremos qué se puede hacer

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias casuísticas, estando mi programa activo.
Si en mi sesion (ade admin) abro prueba.exe mi programa finaliza el proceso prueba.exe y aparece código 5
Mismo caso, pero lanzando prueba.exe con runas.exe (para que lo lance con otro usuario pero sin permisos d admin) también finaliza el proceso prueba.exe con código 5.
El tema está es que si cambio la sesión (dejando la de admin abierta con mi programa observando), y en esa otra ssión abro prueba.exe, vuelvo a mi sesión de admin y no finaliza el "prueba.exe" y aparce el código 6.
No sé interpretar esos códigos, supongo que el 5 es buena señal poruqe lo finaliza, pero el 6 no tengo ni idea de qué significa ni cómo lo puedo arreglar.
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias de nuevo.